# T-SQL - Child - Parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, parent

I created after update trigger, which create Parent from child.

So after update if Account don't exist to Contact, trigger will create Account with "firstname + lastname + Household" as Name. For connection I am using extra column on account where I store contact_ID. After insert I run update on Contact Table where I put created Account's ID into appropriate column. Is there any way to avoid using the extra column? How do I get the account_id?

```
BEGIN
if not exists (select * from Account as A 
                    join inserted as I on a.account_ID=i.account_fk where a.deleted=0)
begin

insert into account
(
 Auto_Create_ID
,Name
) 
select 
     i.contact_ID       AS OLD_ID**strong text**
    ,isnull(i.firstname,'') + ' ' + i.lastname + ' Household' AS Name 
from inserted AS I
where isnull(i.lastname,'')<>''


update C
set C.Account_FK=a.Account_ID
from Contact AS C
join Account AS A on C.Contact_ID=a.Auto_Create_ID
where a.Deleted=0 and c.Contact_ID in
(select Contact_ID from inserted)


end
```

Thank you

Comment: So you want the ID of the account after creation and then link it to Contact?

Comment: Do you want to do this only after `UPDATE`, or after an `INSERT` as well? Can an `UPDATE` leave behind old rows in `account` that should be deleted?

Comment: You can use an [`OUTPUT` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) on the `INSERT` statement to retrieve any or all of the columns, e.g. `Auto_Create_ID` and any other columns that you need to correlate the assigned id's to the data from `inserted`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an `IDENTITY` column for `Auto_Create_ID`, then immediately after your insert statement, you could use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the key of the newly inserted row.